# Пакеты в Postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, пакет

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в Postgresql 10 группировать функции в пакеты наподобие pl/sql?

Comment: START TRANSACTION

Comment: Не понял. Это же относится к управлению транзакциями. Я имею виду пакет как набор функций. Чтобы можно было обратиться - пакет.функция().

Comment: Нет, пакетов нету. Групируйте [другими способами](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-porting.html).